# How does printf( __( ) ); work?

Tags: php, templates, localization

Today I work through a theme to get a better understanding of WordPress and templating.
I discovered this:

```
<?php 
printf( 
    __('Designed by %s', 'Anyword'), 
    '<a href="http://www.example.com">Blub</a>'
); 
?>
```

I know it shows "Designed by Blub"  (Where Blub is linked)
But what does the `__()` mean or why is there a string insert? What for is the Anyword?

Can someone exactly explain this line for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used for [translate text](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology).

The second argument is a [kind of namespace](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) (called domain here) to retrieve the translation (for example from a dedicated file or something else).

So `Anyword` here, should be the guy behind the template, or the company or what ever that can be a domain/namespace.

**edit:**

The doc from wordpress give more explanation on how to [internationalizing a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Internationalizing_Your_Plugin):

---

Add this to the Plugin code to make sure the language file(s) are loaded:

```
load_plugin_textdomain('your-unique-name', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
```

To fetch a string simply use `__('String name','your-unique-name');` to return the translation or `_e('String name','your-unique-name');` to echo the translation. Translations will then go into your plugin's /languages folder.

---

For your plugin/theme, the `your-unique-name` seems to be `Anyword`.

Comment: There are some language files in the theme. How does the arguement know to use them for only the 'Anyword'?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better part from the WP doc.